# How charge interact with mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, charge, mass

If mass does not interact with charge, why does the mass of an electron move (means by which mechanism it moves) in an electromagnetic field? It is same like we stick ball on magnet with fevistic and than that magnet move due to magnetic force towards other magnet also that ball moved with that magnet it moves because of sticky force not magnetic force right ?? So there is some force in first place that bound charge with mass right?? so mass moves with charge in electromagnetic field due to that mustric force that bound charge with mass and not moving under electromagnetic field interaction .sir please tell am I right or wrong ??

Comment: Because of the force, which is $\vec F = q\vec E + q\vec v\times\vec B$, where $q$ is the charge. If this force is the *net* force then the electron accelerates: $\vec a = \vec F/m$, where $m$ is its mass.

Comment: But Lorentz force is purely electromagnetic and EM force can't apply on mass as it is seprate from charge

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Is this a personal theory of yours, or are you trying to explain something within mainstream physics?

Comment: I don't see how this an be considered a homework question, except possibly in a Philosophy of Science course, but it is very unclear.  Mass and electric charge are properties of objects, not objects themselves, so it makes no sense to talk about mass sticking to charge. Philosophers have spent a lot of thought on [properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/) and [objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object/).

Comment: @DavidBailey my fascinating thought is that if charge can't interact with mass how they have got bounded in first 0lace when electron was formed and someone marked this question as homework like

Answer (score 1):

In short, particles are entities, you cannot separate the mass of a particle from its charge. If you have a charged particle with charge $q$ and mass $m$ in an electromagnetic field $(\vec{E},\vec{B})$, where $\vec{E}$ is the electric field and $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field, then a force $\vec{F}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ is going to act on it, where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the particle (it might be zero initially, if it was not moving before the electromagnetic field acted on it). This will cause the particle to feel an acceleration $\vec{a}=\vec{F}/m$, which will gradually modify its velocity as time passes. Since the mass is a property of the particle, same as its electric charge, you cannot have the charge move separately while the mass stays somewhere else, which is what I interpret from your question.

I will explain it with a simple analogy. Imagine that you (the electromagnetic field) are in a room with objects of different shapes (mass) and colors (charge). You pick up only objects that are blue (have charge). If you pick up a specific blue object and see that it is square, why did you pick the square object if you are only choosing based on colors? Well, because it was blue (charged). You cannot pick up the blue color and leave the square shape (mass) behind, it's an object with those two properties!

Comment: Thanks sir now I understand from your analogy but I confused for as you mentioned why charge not sepreatly travell from mass as mass is nor react to electromagnetic field sir thanks

Comment: It is same like we stick ball on magnet  with fevistic  and than that magnet move due to magnetic force towards other magnet also that ball moved with that magnet it moves because of sticky force not magnetic force right ?? So there is some force in first place that bound charge with mass right??  so mass moves with charge in electromagnetic field due to that mustric force that bound charge with mass and not moving under electromagnetic field interaction .sir please tell am I right or wrong ??

Comment: @MehulDangar You seem to think of the properties of objects (such as their mass, or their electric charge) as things that are somehow bounded to those objects. This is not how we understand nature so far. There is not such a thing as a "pure object", devoid of qualities, to which you can stick properties such as mass or charge, as if it were a fridge where you stick different magnets that can be removed and changed. These properties are in the nature of the objects themselves, and they cannot be separated from them.

Comment: @MehulDangar Fundamental particles, like an electron for example, are indivisible entities that have certain properties, such as a certain value of their electric charge, mass, spin, and so on. You cannot separate one of this properties from the electron itself. Can you imagine picking up a white ball and somehow ending up with the color white in your hands while the ball remains behind, without color?

Comment: @MehulDangar Just another funny analogy to help you understand: you are a person that has a certain mass, and this is why you can walk on the floor and not float away, because the gravitational force that the planet Earth acts on your mass and keeps you connected to the floor. If your mass was a property that existed independently of you, sort of bounded to you somehow, the Earth would attract your mass and "the rest of you" (your ghost, maybe?) would float away to outer space :)

Comment: @MehulDangar That doesn't happen, because your mass is inseparable from you. Each one of the particles that form you are particles that have mass, and they cannot lose it, that's what they are, that's what they are like. In short, you cannot separate the properties of objects from the objects themselves, because those properties are what make them what they are. I hope this helped!

Comment: @wipd feather sir thanks your response and answer are great it help me lot but some how this type of question fascinating my mind like one side people saying mass can't interact with charge and in first place elementry particles like charge and mass are somehow bounded and in sepreble from object because it is property of object .so mind always think that how in first place they charge and mass got bounded if they not interact means when electron formed but someone still mark question as homework like